# Structured array from individual field arrays (python, numpy)

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to make an structured array `data` like

```
dtype_test = [
('a', np.int16),
('b', np.int16),
]
data = np.array( [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)], dtype=dtype_test)
```

However, I only have individual fields array; (1,3,5) and (2,4,6).
In other words, I have data `data['a']` and `data['b']` already made.
How can I directly make `data` from these individual arrays?

Comment: Isn’t this just `zip()`? I’m curious to know where your data is coming from, where it’s going, and why you’ve chosen a NumPy array.

Comment: Use `np.rec.fromarrays`

Comment: It's easy and fast to assign values by field. `data['a'] = [1,3,5]` and similarly for `data['b']`.  Many of the `recfunction` functions do this kind of by-field copying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean going backwards?:

```
np.array(list(zip(data['a'], data['b'])), dtype=dtype_test)                                                                                               
# array([(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)], dtype=[('a', '<i2'), ('b', '<i2')])
```

or

```
np.array(list(zip((1,3,5), (2,4,6))), dtype=dtype_test)                                                                                                   
# array([(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)], dtype=[('a', '<i2'), ('b', '<i2')])
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I want.

Comment: @KeitaMizukoshi that is great! Would you be so kind as to hit the checkmark button under the up/down arrows in my question if you think i should get credit for the right answer? thx in advance!